# GuzzleHttp 6 Handler breaks POST

Tags: php, post, middleware, guzzle

I'm trying to implement middleware to GuzzleHttp version 6 in order to attach a custom Exception handler for my package. However I've run into a very weird problem I just can't seem to wrap my head around.

I'm able to push the middleware like this

---

```
    $stack = new HandlerStack();
    $stack->setHandler(new CurlMultiHandler());
    $stack->push(Middleware::mapResponse(function (ResponseInterface $response) {

        if($response->getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new \MyException(sprintf('%s',$response->getBody()),$response->getStatusCode());
        }
   }));

   $client = new Client(['handler' => $stack]);
```

Now when I send a post request, POST params don't get sent with the request. So doing something like this

---

```
$client->post('URI', ['form_params' => ['some' => 'params']]);
```

Now specifically for Instagram API I get response in the manner of "You must provide a client_id", even tought client_id is present in params.

Now removing the handler and running the same request everything works with no problem.

Can anybody help me out here and let me know what am I missing

Thank you